# Yup only run second check after first one has been meet

Tags: react-hook-form, yup

I only want to run the matches when the string values has at least an @ followed by . in the string. What I have below using the **test()** is canceling out the second **matches()**.

**Example of what I'm after:**

user types in value = xx@xxx.x I only want to run the matches() if the one above is true ? How would I go about this using yup. My yup is checking after ever onChange event fires.

```
const regex =
  /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

export const emailSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
    .string()
    .test('dontCheckUntil', '', (_, context: AnyObject) => {
      return /@.\./.test(context.originalValue)
    })
    .matches(regex, { message: 'Invalid Email' }),
})
```

Tried using when but I'm not sure I can use it like this as its throwing an error :

> Uncaught Error: application 'myapp' died in status
> LOADING_SOURCE_CODE: Cyclic dependency, node was:"email"

```
export const emailSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
    .string()
    .when('email', {
      is: (val: string) => {
        console.log('val = ', val)
        return true
      },
      then: (schema) => {
        console.log('schema = ', schema)
        return schema
      },
    })
    .matches(regex, { message: 'Invalid Email' }),
})
```

Comment: Is the regex for `/@.\./` is accurate?

Comment: Yes. I think I need an if else setup in yup.